hot to copy resources in cocoapods from zip file
I have the next structure of my podspec file
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'framework'
  spec.version = '0.0.1'
  spec.homepage = 'https://google.com'
  spec.source = { :http => 'https://gitlab.wnb:28443/api/v4/projects/some_zip.zip' }
  spec.authors = 'My Comp'
  spec.license = 'My Comp Commercial'
  spec.summary = 'Api'
  spec.static_framework = true
  spec.vendored_frameworks = "framework.xcframework"
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '15.0'
end

spec.source points to a zip file hosted on GitLab
some_zip.zip file contains inside 2 folders:
some_resources - folder with resources for framework
framework.xcframework - framework by itself
after pod install only framework was copied to project's pod folder
How do you copy some_resources as well?
I tried to add spec.resources = ['some_resources'] but instead got and empty folder in project
If I'm using local pods and have the same structure with podspec placed in the folder containing spec.source = { :path => './'} everything works as expected
